# SSMA mysql to mssql

Tags: migration, sql-server-2016

I try to convert mysql data base to mssql, I used SSMA.
At first I converted schema from mysql to mssql, then I synchronized it.
Finally I migrated data's and faced with these errors:
Column 'column1 for example' does not allow DBnull.vallue

used softwares:
sql server 2016
mysql work bench 6.1
SSMA

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I’d like to suggest you either change the source data to ‘0000-00-01’ works well with ‘Zero-date in NOT NULL Columns’ or set destination column to NULL so you could process null data after the migration is complete.